# error with LuaLaTeX, lstinputlisting and an extension-less file

Tags: listings, luatex

I'm having troubles with LuaLaTeX and the `listings` package: the former doesn't seem to accept me performing `\lstinputlisting` on a filename that doesn't have an extension.

Minimal example:

`Makefile`:

```
hello: hello.c
    cc -o hello hello.c
```

`test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{Makefile}
\end{document}
```

pdfLaTeX is successful, LuaLaTeX displays the following error:

```
! Package Listings Error: File `Makefile(.tex)' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name:
```

I'm using the freshest versions from TeXLive 2012 (pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13, LuaTeX beta-0.70.2-2012052410).

What's the trouble?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: See also [a related problem with `\IfFileExists`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234750/5100).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem has been mentioned on the luatex mailing list:
http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/luatex/2013-February/004042.html

The problem is that LaTeX is using `\openin` and `\ifeof` to test for the existence of a file and this test fails for files without extensions (despite the fact that the (primitive) `\input` itself would work).

The problem is not confined to luatex: In miktex your example fails with pdflatex too.

With luatex there is a work around: `\openin` accepts arguments with braces and this seems to protect the file name. So you can use `\lstinputlisting{{Makefile}}`.

Comment: As far as I can see the workaround with two `{{`/`}}` doesnt work anymore with current luatex.

Answer (score 1):

I use **MiKTeX**.

To correct this issue, I add a dot after the `Makefile` filename:

```
\lstinputlisting{Makefile.}
```

References: [MiKTeX](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=11734925) and [miktex-users](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.miktex/3385)

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, it seems that this works with neither pdfLaTeX nor LuaLaTeX on Linux.