# LuaTeX, unable to read file in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, luatex

I am trying to switch to LuaTeX, but I am not able to compile any `pgfplots` figures with external data files, which used to compile with `pdflatex`.
Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=6cm, compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot[black] table {plot};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With the plot file.

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
```

With `pdflatex` this works fine, which means that `pgfplots` should be able to read the file.
But when I use `LuaLaTeX` it raises the following error:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'plot'.
In case you intended to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed up your 
end-of-lines? Try  `row sep=crcr' and terminate your lines with `\\' 
(refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details).
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any extension for `plot`? May be `plot.dat` or `plot.txt`? I find no problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the error with `lualatex` if I use `plot` instead of `plot.dat` or `plot.txt`. Try with the file extension like `\addplot[black] table {plot.dat};`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=6cm, compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{plot.dat}
  0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot[black] table {plot.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\addplot[black] table {plot};`, it won't work with `pdflatex` too. For more on the these see [this question and its answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111747/11232) (Thanks to Ulrike Fischer for the link).

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111747/error-with-lualatex-lstinputlisting-and-an-extension-less-file

Comment: Thank you both, since i work on linux i was not aware that not using any file extension would be ever problematic.