# Error with LuaLaTeX, tcolorbox with the listings library and an extension-less file

Tags: luatex, tcolorbox, tcbinputlisting

I have a quite similar problem as this one:

[error with LuaLaTeX, lstinputlisting and an extension-less file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111747/error-with-lualatex-lstinputlisting-and-an-extension-less-file/390892#390892)

Compilation of the MWE below fails with this error message:

```
! Package Listings Error: File `coucou(.tex)' not found.
```

The double-braces hack works fine with the plain `listings` package.  However I'm stuck with the same problem using the `tcolorbox` package and the `listings` library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}

coucou

\tcbinputlisting
{
    listing file = {{coucou}} ,
    listing only ,
}

\end{document}
```

Any idea?

Comment: On windows the other answer in the old question works for me: `\tcbinputlisting { listing file = {testnoext.} , listing only , }`.

Comment: I'm using UNIX (NetBSD) with TeX Live 2017 and this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

In cygwin texlive which I think should act in a similar way it works to use

```
    listing file = {{coucou} } ,
```

with an extra space

Comment: I would never have thought of such an awful hack.  But it just works!  Thanks a lot David!

Comment: @MarcBaudoin I am sure what you meant to say was "thank you for your insightful and elegant code contribution" :-)

Comment: Well of course!  Even tough I still don't understand how such an elegant and awful hack can work...

Comment: @MarcBaudoin always in tex if you have an argument that consists of a single `{}` group the `{}` is stripped.  which is why `\fbox{a}` is `\fbox a`  it seems listings passes the argument through two levels of macro expansion so needs the braces doubled, but with tcolorbox it is more than 2 and possibly variable number depending on the code path rather than use multiple `{{{{coucou}}}` and guess the exact number needed I added the space to ensure the argument does not consist just of a brace group, as it is a brace group and a space the group will survive any number of macro expansion steps

Comment: So that's more than juste a hack, awesome!  And thanks again because I was really stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

With the recent update to the LaTeX kernel, that allows using spaces in file names, the `{{file} }` hack doesn't work anymore.  Is there a solution, other than adding a dummy extension (`.whatever`) to all my extension-less file names?